# req.body.Dates is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sql-server, express

I have 2 drop down menus that are dynamically being populated using SQL Server. Based on the selected items, I am loading a different ejs template. I have done this using the help of AJAX. However, I want to be able to load the data according to the selected criteria. For instance, if `DD1` is selected as `Andrew` and `DD2` as `Date` the table should load 7 columns based on those conditions.

AKA

`SELECT * FROM exTable x WHERE x.Name = 'Andrew' and x.Date = '4/22/2019'`

**What I have already tried** is to pass the selected item from the dropdown to the router, like so:

**router.js**

```
router.post('/selection', async (req, res) =>{
  try {
    var nameFromDB = await conn.query("SELECT DISTINCT pr.Name FROM WFS.Table1 pr WHERE pr.Group = 'Test'");
    var dateFromDB = await conn.query('SELECT r.Date FROM WFS.Table2 r');
    var tables = ("SELECT * FROM WFS.view v WHERE v.Date= '" + req.body.Dates + "' AND v.Name = '" + req.body.Names + "'");
    console.log("SELECT * FROM WFS.view v WHERE v.Date= '" + req.body.Dates + "' AND v.Name = '" + req.body.Names + "'");
       res.render('selection', {tables: tables, nameFromDB : nameFromDB , dateFromDB: datesFromDB});
    } 
      catch (err) {
        res.status(500)
        res.send(err.message)
    }
 });
```

This is the output of the `console.log` :

```
SELECT top 100 * FROM WFS.view_workRequests_Extended v WHERE v.Revenue_Release_Id = '04/16/2019' AND v.Development_Manager = 'Andrew'
```

**app.js**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));
app.use('/', router);
```

**index.ejs**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#DDD').on('change', function(event) {
     var selectedDate = $('#selections option:selected').val();
   });
   $('#DDN').on('change', function(event) {
     var selectedName = $('#selection option:selected').val();
   });

   $('#submitData').on('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/selection",
       data: {selectedDate : selectedDate, selectedName : selectedName },
       success: function() {
         alert('success');
       }
     });
   });
 });    
</script>
<form action="/selection" method="POST">
  <select class="DateDD" id="DDD" name="Dates">
    <% for(var n=0; n < dateFromDB.recordset.length; n++) { %>
      <option><%= dateFromDB.recordset[n].Date%></option>
    <% } %>
  </select>
  <select class="NameDD" id="DDN" name="Names">
    <% for(var n=0; n < nameFromDB.recordset.length; n++) { %>
      <option><%= nameFromDB.recordset[n].Name%></option>
    <% } %>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submitData" class="btn btn-primary" value="View Report" />
</form>
```

**selection.ejs**

**CONTAINS THE SAME THING AS INDEX.EJS (besides the script tag) AND ...**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
  <% for(var n=0; n < tables.recordset.length; n++) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=tables.recordset[n].Name%></td>
      <td><%=tables.recordset[n].Date%></td>
      ....
      ....
    </tr>
  <% } %>
</table>
```

After form submit on `index.ejs` this error gets thrown:

**Dates is not defined**

I don't know whats causing this error, because I am able to see the name and date in the console being printed. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You've intercepted `onsubmit` event and modified the `names` of the data sent through `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/selection",
  data: {selectedDate : selectedDate, selectedName : selectedName }, // <-- here
  success: function() {
    alert('success');
  }
});
```

So you're reading the wrong property in your `req.body`. You should instead read like:

```
// for date
req.body.selectedDate
// for name
req.body.selectedName
```

Also you claim

> I am able to see the name and date in the console

The output of console you've put doesn't match the query in the code in question.

Comment: `req.body.selectedDate` and `req.body.selectedName` are both `Undefined`

Comment: can you post the result of `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: `{ Dates: '04/16/2019', Names: 'Andrew', Submit: 'View Report' }`

Comment: Your req.body contains Dates, so `Dates` is not defined where? Server or ejs?

Comment: `req.body.selectedDate` this is undefined on the server when I console.log it. However, req.body.Dates gives me `04/16/2019` on the server

Comment: Your original error `After form submit on index.ejs this error gets thrown: Dates is not defined`? also are you posting from `index.ejs` or `selection.ejs`

Comment: Ohh that is on the ejs page

Answer (score 0):

This is basic debugging question.
I can advice you to do couple of things like:

- Check the browser devTools ([network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference)) to see if the body payload is being passed to the server.
- On the server (express), are you using body parser middleware ? see more [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) (**req.body** section).
- Try to run nodejs with **inspect** mode and attach your IDE (VSCode is a good one) and add some breakpoints. Alternatively, you can do some `console.log`s in order to check what are you getting from the client.
- You can simulate a browser request using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to check the server side and make sure it is working fine.

Comment: Will try this, thank you! Also, I am using VSCode and edited my question to add the middleware.

Comment: `console.log(req.body.rel)` gives me the date `4/19/2016`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple error, so no big deal, frustrating as I know it can be.

I see you using dates, date, Date & Dates. I would look for a line number reference to give me a clue. I would use chrome and developer tools or console.log to see how far I get.

Or, I would use a different name convention like date1, date2, date3, date4 or something that is even more descriptive, so I knew for sure which date was what, then on narrowing down the error, it will be much easier to fix.

Comment: Cleared up some of the code for better readability, hopefully that helps?

Comment: in your form it looks to me to be this section that is not getting through: <select class="DateDD" id="DDD" name="Dates"> <% for(var n=0; n < dates.recordset.length; n++) { %> <option><%= dates.recordset[n].Date%></option> <% } %> </select> sadly this notes format does not format.... no pun intended.

Comment: ../ the error is signified by name="Dates", so I would look at the code that follows. You can test it by putting in a simple option value like <option value='testvalue'>. Look up the HTML option code and see where you could put a simple value. 

A simple alternative / additional test would be <option value='testvalue'>expectedDateValue</option>


and then see what you get when you run it, obviously not a date, but it will telll you more about where the error and the solution might be found.

Comment: in router.js ...

after:
router.post('/selection', async (req, res) =>{

 console.log('Dates:',Dates);

try...

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Dates is not defined` is the error I receive

Comment: yes it is in the try section that it is not finding Dates. Before you submit can you see something to select and do you select it?

Comment: No, the page loads with that error. I believe I need to carry over the selected values from the `index` page to the `selection` page somehow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192283/discussion-between-david-white-and-caitlinp).